# Are there any tools for aligning dynamic disks in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, alignment

On the heels of [THIS](https://superuser.com/questions/210675/what-does-it-mean-when-people-talk-about-misaligned-hard-drives) question, I would like to ask, are there any tools that can make life easier for aligning windows 7 partitions with dynamic disks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Paragon's tool](http://www.paragon-software.com/business/partition-alignment/) (we lucked out and picked it up for FREE during a promo, you might manage the same if you watch long enough) which works like a charm and I believe will work with pretty much any partition scheme out there.  Basically you just point it at the partitions, it boots into a special environment, rebuilds them, and you're good to go.

If you don't want to use any third party software, you're better off formatting from scratch.  (Keep in mind, if you're using Windows, that Vista and 7 align partitions correctly when they create them, but if the drive was originally formatted with XP you need to rebuild the partitions.)

Comment: I just tried Paragon's tool, it doesen't seem to do Dynamic disks.

Comment: Oh yuck, I was afraid that might happen.  You may just be out of luck then and need to rebuild it by hand if you have a compelling reason for dynamic disks over basic; I don't know of any other reliable automated solutions at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
I wrote a tool called Dynamic Disk Partitioner, this tool can move dynamic disk extents to a different position on the disk, this can be used to align the extent to a 4K alignment.

The tool is available at:
http://vm1.duckdns.org/Public/DynamicDiskPartitioner/DynamicDiskPartitioner.htm

Be sure to backup any critical data!

Tal Aloni